# AppBar back arrow not working when using android.R.id.home - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, optionmenu

I'm trying to use `android.R.id.home:` in options menu item click, but it's not working as it always does, I've a menu with search box and there I'm using `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"`.

I'm also using navigation drawer toggle, and switching drawer toggle with `setDisplayHomeAsUp(true);`

maybe because of `collapseActionView`(in menu.xml) or the `drawerToggle`(in MainActivity.java) my `android.R.id.home:` not working in `MainActivity.java`

please help me.

my menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_search"
        android:id="@+id/options_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSystemGrey"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">
    </item>
</menu>
```

on options menu item click

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // do stuff
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled` too, in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate():

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```